# Actualizar proyecto de Flutter 1 a Flutter 3

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Buenas he retomado un proyecto que hice hace unos años en Flutter 1 y me gustaría actualizarlo a su última versión. Algún consejo o tip para hacer, ya que algunas librerías ya están en desuso. Y no consigo arrancar la app.

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que te recomendaría hacer para saber cuales son los paquetes que están desactualizados y como actualizarlos es usando este comando:

```
flutter pub outdated
```

O puedes actualizar todas las dependencias compatibles con este comando:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Ahora si tu aplicación no usa muchos `paquetes`, podrías buscando uno por uno en [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) y actualizarlos uno a uno. Es cierto que es un cambio brusco el que vas a hacer, desde `Flutter` 1 a 2 lo que interviene ahí es el `null safety` que esto se está viendo desde `Flutter 2`, entonces, te recomiendo leer un poco la documentación de `Flutter 2` [aquí](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2021/03/04/flutter-2-todas-las-novedades-presentadas-en-flutter-engage/) y `Flutter 3` [aquí](https://docs.flutter.dev/whats-new) para que sepas que cambios vas a tener que hacer en tu código, por otro lado también van a haber paquetes que ya no se los está usando o no son compatibles con `null safety`, pero puede haber variantes a estos paquetes, una vez que entiendas todo eso puedes hacer un:

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Y con eso actualizarías a la última versión de Flutter.